# Visual Studio 2010 C++ dll problems when trying to run application on another PC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, inno-setup

I have a program that I made an installer for using Inno Setup. When I run the application on PC 1, which is the PC I wrote the code for, the program runs fine with no errors.

I want to be able to run the program on PC 2 that doesn't have visual studio 2010 installed. So I installed the [C++ Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) on PC 2 (both win 7) and put all the required dll's that were needed from an SDK that I was using into the same directory as the exe file. For some reason though, when I try to run the application it just crashes.

I know that the problem has something to do with the dll's being in the same place as the exe, this is becuase I tried the same thing on PC 1 which was working and sure enough the program crashes as soon as I put the dll's in the same directory. On PC 2 though, when I move the dll's somewhere else I get an error saying that the dll's are missing.

So I put the dll's in a separate folder and created a new PATH variable to the dll's. The program still crashes. I ran [dependancy walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to the exe and I get these errors. Are these dll's supposed to be in the same directory as the others?

[image]

I'm not sure why else my program won't run on another computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1** I have located the instance at which the program crashed in event monitor. It seems to relate to KERNALBASE.dll

[image]

**Edit 2** Apparently I need to add more details. Both computers have the same version .NET framework installed. They both run Windows 7 Professional. They are both 64-bit. The application that I made uses an SDK with dll's. These dll's have been added to the directory of the program so that the second computer can recognize them. I have tried other methods to export the code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293568(v=vs.100).aspx), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293575(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384837.aspx). All of them did the same thing. I believe that the problem has something to do with the dll's but i'm no expert, which is why i'm asking for help.

Comment: You haven't don't enough debugging. "It just crashes". "I get an error." It's as if you are ignoring the details. Get some diagnostics. Find out how it fails. Perhaps there's a defect in your code. Make a simple MCVE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I located the error in event monitor when the program crashed. It seems to relate to KERNALBASE.dll.

Comment: I am new to C++ but i'm assuming you re refering to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What code do you want to look at? The release executable runs fine on the machine that I wrote the code on.

Comment: Isolate the problem so that it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application 64bit? Then you need to install 64bit MSVC++ runtime.

If no then you need to install 32 bit MSVC++ Runtime. 32bit runtime (x86) is installed **also** on 64 bit machines for 32bit apps.

The same applies for (third) party Dlls: they need to be copied to appropriate folder (System32 vs SysWOW64) for 32/64bit dlls.

Comment: I have added an edit where I found the problem to be relating to KERNALBASE.dll